# Is there a simple command to make NERDTree switch sides?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Sometimes I want to be able to quickly move NERDTree to the left or right side of a vim session. If I type

```
let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "Left"
```

for example, then I have to type `:NERDTreeToggle` twice to get it to move.

Is there a simple command for toggling the position of NERDTree?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
command! NT let g:NERDTreeWinPos = !NERDTreeWinPos | NERDTreeToggle | NERDTreeToggle | execute("normal \<C-w>p")
```

Then `:NT` sets the NERDTreeWinPos to the opposite side, toggles twice, and executes CTRL-p to move the cursor back to the previous pane.

It's not very pretty but it works. Does anyone have a better solution?